# How to map many to many relation to a list with dapper

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

I have a class AnalysisRule

```
public class AnalysisRule
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Analysis Analysis { get; set; }
    public AnalysisCategory AnalysisCategory { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public bool FatherHerdBookRequired { get; set; }
    public bool MotherHerdBookRequired { get; set; }
    public List<Breed> AllowedBreeds { get; set; }
}
```

That has a list of Breeds

```
public class Breed
{
    public long BreedId { get; set; }
    public long AnimalTypeId { get; set; }
    public long BreedCode { get; set; }
    public string BreedName { get; set; }
    public string BreedAcronym { get; set; }
}
```

This is a many to many relationship that I bind together with a DB table 
AnalysisRulesBreeds
[image]

Breeds

[image]

And AnalysisRules
[image]

With Dapper I have tried

```
    var sql = @"select *
                from ""AnalysisRules"" 
                join ""AnalysisCategory"" on ""AnalysisRules"".""AnalysisCategoryId"" = ""AnalysisCategory"".""Id""  
                join ""Analysis"" on ""AnalysisRules"".""AnalysisId"" = ""Analysis"".""Id""
                left join ""AnalysisRulesBreeds"" on ""AnalysisRulesBreeds"".""AnalysisRuleId"" = ""AnalysisRules"".""Id""
                left join ""Breed"" on ""AnalysisRulesBreeds"".""BreedId"" = ""Breed"".""BreedId""
                where ""AnalysisId"" = :AnalysisId";
    rules = sqlConnection.QueryAsync<AnalysisRule, AnalysisCategory, Analysis, Breed, AnalysisRule>(
        sql,
        (ar, c, a, b) =>
        {
            ar.AnalysisCategory = c;
            ar.Analysis = a;
            ar.Breeds.Add(b);
            return ar;
        },
        new
        {
            AnalysisId = analysisId
        },
        splitOn:"BreedId");
```

Which gives me

> ´When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id
>   Parameter name: splitOn

If I run the same query in SQL Developer I get 2 rows out with same Id but with different data in Breed, so the query should be good enough.

So how do I get these 2 rows into one AnalysisRule entity where Breeds consist of 2 Breed entities?

**EDIT**
I now have

```
                    sqlConnection.Open();

                var sql = @"select  ar.*,
                                    ac.*,
                                    b.*                 

                            from ""AnalysisRules"" ar
                            join ""AnalysisCategory"" ac on ar.""AnalysisCategoryId"" = ac.""Id""  
                            join ""Analysis"" a on ar.""AnalysisId"" = a.""Id""

                            left join ""AnalysisRulesBreeds""  on ""AnalysisRulesBreeds"".""AnalysisRuleId"" = ar.""Id""
                            left join ""Breed"" b  on ""AnalysisRulesBreeds"".""BreedId"" = b.""Id""

                            where ""AnalysisId"" = :AnalysisId";

                var rules = sqlConnection.QueryAsync<AnalysisRule, AnalysisCategory, Analysis, Breed, AnalysisRule>(
                    sql,
                    (ar, c, a, b) =>
                    {
                        ar.AnalysisCategory = c;
                        ar.Analysis = a;
                        ar.Breeds.Add(b);
                        return ar;
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        AnalysisId = analysisId
                    });

                return await rules;
```

Removed the splitOn, changed AnalysisRulesBreedsId to Id but I still get

> When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id
>   Parameter name: splitOn

If I do the same query in SQLDev I get
[image]

Answer (score 2):

By selecting * you get the columns of every joined table. Also you set `splitOn`to `BreedId`. Now Dapper expects that to separate the row columns of one joined table from the next, it should look for a column named `BreedId`.

This does not work because all tables except `AnalysisRulesBreeds` use `Id` as id column name.

Try removing the `splitOn` parameter, then it will default to `Id`. Then adjust your select-clause to only select from the tables you actually need in the result, eg.

`select AnalysisRule.*, AnalysisCategory.*, Analysis.*, Breed.*`

(assuming that your Analysis table and AnalysisCategory table follow the convention of having an Id column named ´Id´).

Comment: Have tried to edit with your suggestions, but I still get the same error even though I only use Id as PK in all the tables, see the edit part for a screenshot of the data I get in SQLDev

Comment: If the result Dapper receives contains the id-column names shown in your screen dump (Id, Id_1, Id_2), then it will not work. An Oracle-thing? Same query in SQL Server would name the id-columns Id, Id and Id...

Comment: Is it then possible for me to name every column explicit like ac."Id" as "AnalysisCategoryId" and do a spliton somehow?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to add a comma-delimited list to splitOn, eg "AnalysisCategoryId, BreedId, ...".